# How to add a <a href=""> within a <c:foreach>

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I am able to print the list data throuth c:foreach in a jsp page but i want to  add  another column with some static text in the same table.

```
My Jsp:
     <table border=1 cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" class="altrowstable"
id="alternatecolor" width="100%">
<TR>
    <th width="150px">ERROR CODE</th>
    <th width="650px">ERROR MESSAGE</th>
    <th width="200px">SEVERITY</th>

</TR>
<!-- <TR>
    <td><select  name="Error objs">
        <option value="Select Option"/>
        <options items=${errorlist} itemValue="Err_code" itemLabel="Err_msg"/>
        </select>
    </td>
</TR> -->
<c:forEach var="error" items="${errorlist}">  
<TR>
    <td><c:out value="${error.err_code}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${error.err_msg}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${error.err_severity}"/></td>
    <td><a href="/edit?Err_id=<c:out       value="${error.err_id}"/>">Edit</a></td>  
    <td><a href="/delete?Err_id=<c:out value="${error.err_id}"/>">Delete</a></td>           </TR>
    </c:forEach>
 </table>
```

but when i execute this code my table is not visible on the browser. and when i remove the

```
<td><a href="/edit?Err_id=<c:out value="${error.err_id}"/>">Edit</a></td>  
    <td><a href="/delete?Err_id=<c:out value="${error.err_id}"/>">Delete</a></td>
```

lines from the above code the table is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Two sets of `"` is making syntactical errors. Use a combination of `'` (single) and `"` (double) quotes.

```
<c:forEach var="error" items="${errorlist}">  
<TR>
    <td><c:out value="${error.err_code}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${error.err_msg}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${error.err_severity}"/></td>
    <td><a href='/edit?Err_id=<c:out value="${error.err_id}"/>'>Edit</a></td>  
    <td><a href='/delete?Err_id=<c:out value="${error.err_id}"/>'>Delete</a></td>             
</TR>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the same thins, By using c:set

```
<c:forEach var="error" items="${errorlist}">  
    <c:set var="error_id" value="${error.err_id}" />
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${error.err_code}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${error.err_msg}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${error.err_severity}"/></td>
        <td><a href='/edit?Err_id=<c:out value="${error_id}"/>'>Edit</a></td>  
        <td><a href='/delete?Err_id=<c:out value="${error_id}"/>'>Delete</a></td>             
   </tr>
```